# Press search button to show the searchBar from isHidden to isSelected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I make an if statement in swift that when I click the search button as shown in the picture below to show the search bar from `isHidden` to `isSelected`

Basically when I press the `searchImage` the `searchBar` will show from its initial `isHidden` to `isSelected`

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AxMG.png)

```
@IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: Any) {
    
}

@IBOutlet weak var searchField: UISearchBar!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you need exactly but if you need to switch isHidden or isSelected you can add var to keep the search bar state like:

```
var isSearchFieldHidden: Bool = false{
    didSet{
        self.searchField.isHidden = isSearchFieldHidden
    }
}

@IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: Any) {
    isSearchFieldHidden.toggle()
}

@IBOutlet weak var searchField: UISearchBar!
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the great answer :)

Comment: you are most welcome :)